# embedding zathura with xembed not working

Tags: x, zathura

I'm trying to open pdf files with zathura. When running zathura I'm passing the `-e` option to embed it in suckless' tabbed utility. This works initially, but while any subsequent zathura instances embed successfully in tabbed, they show just a black screen. The pdf files I'm trying to view are generated with man's `-T` option, (and open properly when running zathura on its own) so I think I can rule out issues with zathura choking on the input. 
What I've been trying so far:

```bsh
xid=$(tabbed -d -c)
zathura $path_to_file -e $xid
```

alternately:

```bsh
xid=$(tabbed -d -c)
man -Tpdf $page | zathura - -e $xid
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behavior, although at one try (where I did not change anything, just ran "tabbed -c zathura -e") it worked. Running the command again just gave black windows for subsequent zathura instances.

Comment: Same reported at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wmii/1N5pDT20nq8 in 2016...

Comment: I could solve my issue by running the command from a different place. Currently I'm using awesome as WM, and when I run `tabbed -c zathura -e` from the command box, it won't work. However, it works when I run it from a terminal. I guess that extracting/appending to the passed command does not work from the command box. How did you run tabbed?